# SQL Pivot when column data is in single column with a discriminator column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, sql-server-2014

I have a set of data that represents how people ranked various traits. I am trying to Pivot the data by two columns however, the column data is contained under a single column with a separate column acting as a discriminator.

Here is the scenario. People were given a list of three traits and asked to rank them in order of importance to them. They were given two lists of three traits each and asked to rank each list 1 to 3, from most important to least important.

```
+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+------+
| RecordNo |  Name | QuestionNumber | QuestionGroup | Rank |
+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+------+
|     1    |  Bob  |        1       |       1       |   2  |
|     2    |  Bob  |        2       |       1       |   1  |
|     3    |  Bob  |        3       |       1       |   3  |
|     4    |  Bob  |        1       |       2       |   1  |
|     5    |  Bob  |        2       |       2       |   2  |
|     6    |  Bob  |        3       |       2       |   3  |
|     7    | Sally |        1       |       1       |   3  |
|     8    | Sally |        2       |       1       |   2  |
|     9    | Sally |        3       |       1       |   1  |
|    10    | Sally |        1       |       2       |   1  |
|    11    | Sally |        2       |       2       |   3  |
|    12    | Sally |        3       |       2       |   2  |
+----------+-------+----------------+---------------+------+
```

What I would like to end up with is a PIVOT of the data so it looks like this ..

```
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
| RecordNo |  Name | Question1 | Question2 | Question3 | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
|          |       |  Group 1  |  Group 1  |  Group 1  |   Group 2  |   Group 2  |   Group 2  |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
|     1    |  Bob  |     2     |     1     |     3     |      1     |      2     |      3     |
|     2    | Sally |     3     |     2     |     1     |      1     |      3     |      2     |
+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I know how to do a Pivot on multiple columns [great article on it here](http://www.sqlideas.com/2015/04/pivoting-on-multiple-columns-sql-server.html) but what I cannot figure out is how to Pivot when the data is in the same column (QuestionNumber) separated by a discriminator column (QuestionGroup).

I also created an online table [here](http://rextester.com/FCF58622)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest method for pivoting is conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when questiongroup = 1 and questionnumber = 1 then rank end) as q_1_1,
       max(case when questiongroup = 1 and questionnumber = 2 then rank end) as q_1_2,
       max(case when questiongroup = 1 and questionnumber = 3 then rank end) as q_1_3,
       max(case when questiongroup = 2 and questionnumber = 1 then rank end) as q_2_1,
       max(case when questiongroup = 2 and questionnumber = 2 then rank end) as q_2_2,
       max(case when questiongroup = 2 and questionnumber = 3 then rank end) as q_2_3
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: I think I got so caught up in the PIVOT keyword I forgot to go back to basics.